# How can I simplify these nested for loops with collectors in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I'm very new to the idea of collectors and parallel streams in Java, and am wondering if there's a way to simplify this code:

```
boolean foundAnyMatch = false;
for (MyObject myObject : hashSetOfObjects) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i++) {
        if (myObject.customMethodReturnsBool(arrayOfStrings[i])) {
            foundAnyMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

As you would expect, `hashSetOfObjects` is of type `Set<MyObject>` where the class `MyObject` contains a method with signature `boolean customMethodReturnsBool(String entry)`. Also, `arrayOfStrings` is simply of type `String[]`.

Comment: I doubt using Streams will simplify that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, your code runs for O(n) times on hashSetOfObjects. While your intention is to find if any object in  hashSetOfObjects results truly in nested code. 
Same logic can be represented using streams as:

```
boolean foundAnyMatch = hashSetOfObjects.stream
                           .anyMatch(x -> arrayOfStrings.streams
                                            .anyMatch(y -> x.customMethodReturnsBool(y)));
```

Comment: When I typed this up I immediately got compiler errors, but it led me on the right path. Here's how I tweaked your code:

`boolean foundAnyMatch = hashSetOfObjects.stream().anyMatch(x -> Arrays.stream(arrayOfStrings).anyMatch(y -> y.customMethodReturnsBool(x)));`